# pytest w/ Flask: easy way to pull in our app setup without create_app()?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

We have a Flask app where most of the basic Flask setup code is in a file `run.py` at the root of our application. So basically a lot of this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config(...)
app.config(...)

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(resources.Registration, '/registration')
api.add_resource(...)
api.add_resource(...)
```

I'm trying to add unit testing to it, which we don't currently have. I'm roughly following the Flask tutorial project (https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/1.0.2/examples/tutorial) as an example.

In that, basically you create your entire app as a module that can be imported - and the module is a factory. So `__init__.py` has a `create_app` function that creates your app ([https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0.2/examples/tutorial/flaskr/**init**.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0.2/examples/tutorial/flaskr/__init__.py)). I think this is automatically called when the module is imported by the main app during normal operation, but it can also be explicitly called in conftest.py (https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0.2/examples/tutorial/tests/conftest.py) which I think (?) is automatically called as part of the `pytest` launch.

So my question is actually pretty simple: Is there a decent way we can launch some `pytest` tests without refactoring our main app's code into a factory module? I don't want to touch the main app too much... I'd like to leave it as a really simple setup like my code at the top of this question.

In other words, this is the basic app setup in the tutorial's `conftest.py` once you remove the DB stuff:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():

    app = create_app({
        'TESTING': True,
        'DATABASE': db_path,
    })

    yield app
```

And I want an `app` without `create_app`. But since all of our app code is just in our basic `run.py`, I can't think of a good way to do this other than copying everything and keeping it in sync. I can't import `app` from `run.py` since it's not a module I don't think.

Sorry that this is so basic - neither testing nor import statements are strengths of mine.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a way... just make it so that you can include modules from the parent folder (as per [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)) and then import run and get the variable from that:

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)

import run

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = run.app
    yield app
```

...of course I'll need to find a way to adjust the behavior there for testing purposes (i.e. the equivalent of the tutorial's passing `'Testing': True`), so that's my next challenge.